# Remove repeated values in array and merge the value associated with the second array

Tags: javascript

i have two arrays
the first one is incomeTitle and it contains the following values:

```
let aryOne = ["salary","pension","salary","rent","wages","rent"]
```

and the second array is incomeAmount and it  contains following values:

```
let aryTwo = ["100","900","100","800","5000","200"]
```

> these two arrays values are related : eg-
>
> > salary is 100 and pension is 900 respectively salary is repeated 2
> >     times so salary value should be 200

finally, i want two respective arrays as follows:

```
let incomeTitle = ["salary","pension","rent","wage"]
let incomeAmount = ["200", "900", "1000", "5000"]
```

i tried doing this:

```
for(i=0;i<=noOfIncome;i++){
      for(var j=i+1;j<=noOfIncome;j++){
        if(this.incomeTitle[i]==this.incomeTitle[j]){
          var abc=  parseInt(this.incomeTitleAmount[i])+parseInt(this.incomeTitleAmount[j]);
          this.incomeTitleAmount.push(abc);
          this.incomeTitle.push(this.incomeTitle[i]);
        }
      }
      this.incomeTitle.splice( i, 1 );
      this.incomeTitleAmount.splice(i,1);
    }
```

Comment: so what have you tried ?

Comment: What have you tried? You should at least try then ask questions if you have issues

Comment: use some `if`, `forEach` statements and you can figure it out by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table for the indices with the same value of `array1`.

If a value is found in the hash table, you could add the value to the value at the index of the hash and splice both arrays.

If not found, then take the index and move on with the next index.

```js
var array1 = ["salary", "pension", "salary", "rent", "wages", "rent"],
    array2 = ["100", "900", "100", "800", "5000", "200"],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    i = 0;

while (i < array1.length) {
    if (array1[i] in hash) {
        array2[hash[array1[i]]] = (+array2[hash[array1[i]]] + +array2[i]).toString();
        array1.splice(i, 1);
        array2.splice(i, 1);
        continue;
    }
    hash[array1[i]] = i;
    i++;
}

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
var income = ['salary', 'pension', 'salary', 'rent', 'wages', 'rent'];
var amount = ['100', '900', '100', '800', '5000', '200'];

var income2 = [];
var amount2 = [];

income.forEach((title, i) => {
   let j = income2.indexOf(title);
   let value = parseInt(amount[i]);
   if (j > -1) {
      amount2[j] += value;
   } else {
      income2.push(title);
      amount2.push(value);
   }
});

amount2 = amount2.map(String);

console.info(income2, amount2);
```